# Sitecore Context Database during computeField index

Tags: content-search, sitecore-api

When I call `Sitecore.Context.Database` inside of an `IComputedIndexField`, it returns `Core`. I can't use this to call the `GetItem()` function.

Thus, I wrote the following as a workaround.

```
var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;
if (indexableItem == null)
                {
                    Sitecore.ContentSearch.Diagnostics.CrawlingLog.Log.Warn(this + " : unsupported IIndexable type : " + indexable.GetType());
                    return false;
                }
var category = indexableItem.Item.Database.GetItem(new ID("MY ID"));
```

This works perfectly fine, but is it the correct way to call the `Database` object?

Comment: I can confirm this is how I get items _other_ than the current `Indexable`.

Comment: I use "indexableItem.Item.Database" too.

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is the right way to get the database based on the database of the item being indexed, I think you should get `null` for `Sitecore.Context.Database` because the code is **NOT** running within any site context, Check `Sitecore.Context.Site` to verify (Thats what i see in Sitecore 8.2u5), Maybe in older version, it was running with the context of "**shell**" site, which uses the core database

```
<site name="shell" database="core"  virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" ..... />
```

Comment: Great point. You were right, under the `shell` site, my database is set as `core`. Now, I understand why the `Sitecore.Context.Database` is set to core.